# MakeHuman to Blender texture problem

Tags: texturing, makehuman

I create a 3d character using MakeHuman v1.1. Later, I exported to Blender using Collada format. I have a problem with the textures. The next picture show us the problem. The white part in the skin is the problem. If I reimport using the same format the problem is not present.
[image]

I think that not is a UV mapping problem since that is imported from MakeHuman and Blender is using the default mapping.

Answer (score 1):

An easy fix would be to export in the blender exchange format. All textures should then be displayed correctly.
[image: Make Human Export options]

Comment: Sorry but I try to not reimport anything.

Comment: @user3477118, the best way to work with blender and makehuman  is *.mhx format.